# Homogenous Initial Value Problem's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I've been tasked with the following. Consider $x^\prime(t)=(x^2(t).t^2)/(tx(t))$ with $x(1)=1$.

a) Show the IVP is homogeneous.

b)Find x: I $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ specifying the maximal interval I  where x is defined and solves the equation.

Here's how I started:

I started by defining a homogeneous equation $f:G \longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$  i.e. for λ in $\mathbb{R}$ \{0}: $1. (λt, λx)$ is in $G$ and $2. f(λt,xt)=f(t,x)$  for $(t,x) \in G$.

For $1$, I came to the conclusion that our $G$ is $\mathbb{R}$ \{0} hence for our defined lambda $(λt,λx) \in \mathbb{R}$ \{0} or $G$.

As for two I'm not too sure how to continue as I'm not sure how I can link my given definition for a homogeneous equation to a homogeneous IVP. Do I need to show $λx'(λt)=x'(t)$? I'm not too sure.
p.s. apologies for my poor use of mathjax, I'm quite new to it.

Comment: Strange... isn't $\frac{x^2(t) t^2}{t x(t)} = t x(t)$? Also, can you use MathJax to edit your questions as is supposed to be here? [A basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @coudy An IVP is an initial value problem

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net it seems so, maybe the question is formulated this way so that x(t) and t cannot equal zero? and thank you for the pointer on mathjax